# Lifehacks vs Home Improvement

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to sort out and tidy up in a nice way cables in my home. Will it be related to:

- [Lifehacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/)?
- [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: What do you want to do specifically?

Comment: @Mithrandir Order and tidy up cluttered cables in a specific way

Comment: If it involves following  instructions on labels it's probably Lifehacks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be [on-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for Home Improvement. It *could* be for [Lifehacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) if you're looking for a non-standard way to do it, but we need (way) more details to be sure.

On-topic:

> - seeking uncommon solutions to common physical problems;
> - asking for unusual ways of using everyday objects to achieve a certain task or solve a specific problem;
> - looking for simple and practical tips to life's everyday problems that may not have an obvious solution

Off-topic:

> - conventional "how to…" questions about skills that can commonly be learned elsewhere;